# I am having an error in the below code for event delegation model

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have created one form and two .cs files.

1st file form1.cs:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Class1 _enemy;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _enemy = new Class1(this);
        _enemy.LoopInteration += OnLoopInteration;
        _enemy.MyMethod();
        _enemy.LoopInteration -= OnLoopInteration;
    }
    private void OnLoopInteration(object sender, LoopCounterArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(e.Iteration);
    }
}
}
```

second file class1.cs:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public class LoopCounterArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Iteration { get; set; }

    public LoopCounterArgs(int iteration)
    {
        Iteration = iteration;
    }
}
public class Class1
{
    public event EventHandler<LoopCounterArgs> LoopInteration;
    public Class1(Form1 form)
    {
        _form1 = form;
    }
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
        {
            LoopInteration?.Invoke(this, new LoopCounterArgs(j));
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    private Form1 _form1;
}

}
```

and the form design of form1:

[Form1 Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPAAg.png)

Now am getting the following errors in this:

*Error  1:

> Invalid expression term '.'   c:\users\43060\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\Class1.cs 29  32  WindowsFormsApplication4

Error   2:

> Syntax error, ':' expected    c:\users\43060\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\Class1.cs 29  33  WindowsFormsApplication4*

**What I want is that when user clicks button on form1 the for loop runs in class1.cs and result is displayed in form1 text box.
Strictly want to use Event + Delegation model.**

Comment: It's not clear why your `Class1` has a reference to a form when it doesn't use one - but you also haven't shown us which line has the problem. Given that you've not supplied the `using` directives, we can't map the line numbers in the error messages onto lines in the source code...

Comment: But other than that, your `class1.cs` compiles for me, suggesting there's something else wrong. Are you *actually* using Visual Studio 2013? If so, you can't use the null conditional operator... I'd suggest upgrading to VS2015.

Comment: @JonSkeet gives error in this line
    LoopInteration?.Invoke(this, new LoopCounterArgs(j));

says syntax error.

I am using VS 2012

Comment: Right, so you're using a C# 5 compiler. You can't use C# 6 features with VS2012.

Comment: what to do now @JonSkeet

Comment: I've already said: use a C# 6 compiler (e.g. by using VS2015)... or stop trying to use C# 6 features.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that remove "?"

```
LoopInteration.Invoke(this, new LoopCounterArgs(j));
```

Comment: That will then throw an exception if nothing subscribes to the event. The OP either needs to handle that explicitly, or update to a C# 6 compiler so they can use C# 6 features.